# ReactJS: Why can't I access variables outside the .map method?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, immutable.js

How can I access the constant `answer` from within this map method's function?

If I pass `this` to the map method, `this.props.answer` is defined, but `answer` *is still undefined*.

```
export default class QuestionList extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    question: ImmutablePropTypes.map,
    answer: ImmutablePropTypes.map
  };

  render() {
   const question = this.props.question;
   const inputs = question.get('inputs'); // [Input1, Input2, Input3] 
   const answer = this.props.answer;

   const listBody = inputs.map((input, index) => {
    console.log(answer); // Uncaught ReferenceError: answer is not defined
   });
   return (
     <div>{listBody}</div>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a closing paren for `inputs.map`. Maybe just a typo? But figured I should point it out in case

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. That was a transcription typo--unrelated to the original question.

Comment: ideally this should work. can u provide a codepen link to make it reproduceable for us. Secondly u need to close the map expression with a closing ")" this would cause a syntax error though if its in ur code too.

Comment: Yep you should be able to access the `answer` variable inside that map. Are you certain that that prop is being passed into the component?

Comment: Your actual code must be different. This will work. Every function in JavaScript is a closure, there is no reason why this shouldn't work. Double check that you don't have a typo in the variable names.

Comment: Indeed, the code you've given works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/64372/